# How can I have a uniform buffer array of chars or shorts?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Apparently OpenGL doesn't have types that are 8 bit or 16 bit. I need to send a uniform array with each element of the array consisting of:

```
unsigned short (16 bit) xPosition;
unsigned short (16 bit) yPosition;
unsigned short (16 bit) radius;
```

Each triangle references these values, so I can divide by gl_VertexID to get the current triangle that is being drawn. The problem is that these values are 3 shorts (48bits, 3 bytes) each. If I'm drawing vertex number 8 for example I can do 8 / 3 = 2, and I know I'm drawing triangle 2 (the third triangle), but then how do I index into the uniform buffer to get the xPosition, yPosition and radius? Is there no simple way to just have a uniform buffer array or chars or shorts in glsl?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do the math yourself. You'll have to read one or more unsigned, 32-bit integers and do masking/ bit-shifting to extract the values you're interested in.

By not making this a native feature of GLSL, the API doesn't give you the impression that shorter variable reads will be just as fast as reading 32-bit integers.

That being said, it would probably be better for you to just use a vertex buffer (though vertex data that isn't 4-byte aligned probably isn't a good idea).